# iOS 11: How to create folder (directory) in Simulator

Tags: ios, directory, simulator, file-management, ios11

From iOS 11, Apple has provided a new feature (application) for File Management (Folder/Directory management option).

I'm trying to create a directory from simulator but all options are de-active in the simulator.

How can I enable them? Does simulator support File Manager?

Here are the steps I followed.

[image]

Comment: iOS 11 doesn't allow you to create folders in your device. Files app is just an easy way of handling document provider app files from one app. So, if you don't have any document provider installed, you can't do anything with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operations in the Files app seem to be very unstable at the moment. However if you want to add something there, for example you can:

1. Open the Photos app.
2. Select a photo.
3. Press the Open in button.
4. Select "Markup as PDF".
5. Done -> "Save File to".
6. Save there.

And the a file (and maybe a folder) will get created.

Result UI
[image]

Comment: Does this only work for iPad? Cannot seem to find the option 'Markup as PDF' in the iPhone simulator